# C#, How can I add the certificate to the HttpClientHandler?

Tags: c#, ssl

I need to send data to a web api which needs a certificate to authorize. But I've no clue how I can add the certificate to the handler in .Net 4.5. This is the code:

```
// Import the certificate
X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Import(pathToCertificate, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { })
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        // Build the JSON
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var processResult = await client.PostAsync(uriToServer, httpContent);
        var responseBody = processResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseBody);
    }
}
```

I searched google and found a "HttpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add" but that is .Net Core and not 4.5.

Is this possible with HttpClient or do I have to use the HttpWebRequest class?

**UPDATE:**

Related on the given answer from "Peter Bons" (thanks again) and since the using is only try-finally I changed the code to this:

```
// Create an WebRequestHandler instance
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();

// Add the certificate
var certFile = Path.Combine(pathToWorkingDirectory, "SERVER.PFX");
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile, "password"));

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
try
{
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    //var processResult = await client.GetAsync("https://server/login");
    var processResult = await client.PostAsync("https://server/p/m", httpContent);
    var responseBody = processResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {e}");
}
finally
{
    client.Dispose();
}
```

Unfortunately the Server response with 403 forbidden...
How can I check if the authorization is working with the certificate?

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems like the answer to this question lies in the debugging:
[image]

I tested the password and with the wrong password for the certificate a exception happens. So I am not sure if the server is accepting the certificate but the server path is dead or the server is not accepting the certificate.

**UPDATE 3:**

Looking at the response object showing more information but not if the certificate caused the error.
[image]

But there is a Exception inside the content?
[image]

**UPDATE 4:**

Unfortunately, the server never received the certificate...

**LAST UPDATE**

The problem was the certificate I got from our sysadmin. Code works. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use the `WebRequestHandler` class like in this example:

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();

var certFile = Path.Combine(@"d:\temp\", "cert.pfx");
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certFile, "password"));

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    ....
}
```

See also [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/) for more background information

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the answer. :-) I will read over the background information and will give feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately, our sysadmin told me that the server is never receiving the certificate. Maybe you have the time to look over my updates and check what I did wrong?

Comment: @user3772108 I am 100% sure the code in my answer is correct, but do mind that the web server may need additional information. So you should check with your sysadmin that the server has been configured correctly. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adc0029-8875-4390-a717-e5eb2eba9778. Unfortunately, this is outside the scope of the question and it is hard to help with that. As you can see when debugging the client certificate is being send, so that part works.

Comment: Ok, so the debugging (screenshot) is correct and the client does send the request(POST) with the certificate? Thanks again for your answer. I will check that with our sysadmin.

Comment: You are right! It was the certificate! Unbelievable... Thanks again for your great help! :-)

Comment: A note about the using HttpClient; We should save and reuse our HttClients, not creating new ones when we need them: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/